# ItemAttachment can't be downloaded using EWS

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I am having issues downloading attachments of type 'ItemAttachment' using EWS.
Following is the code that i use to download attachments:

```
 PropertySet ps = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
                    ps.add(ItemSchema.MimeContent);
                    ia = (ItemAttachment) attach;
                    ia.load(ps);
                    //ia.load();
                    System.out.println(ia.getItem().getSubject());
                    MimeContent mc = ia.getItem().getMimeContent();
                    String itemName = ia.getName().replace(" ","").replace(":","-").trim();
                    attname.add(itemName);
                    System.out.println(itemName);
                    byte[] contentBytes = mc.getContent();
                    theStream = new FileOutputStream(
                            "C:\\Users\\502000317\\Desktop\\test\\"
                                    + itemName);
                    ia.getItem().getAttachments();
                    theStream.write(contentBytes);
                    theStream.flush();
```

but when I try to execute this, i get the follwing error :

java.lang.ClassCastException: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.PropertySet cannot be cast to microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.PropertyDefinitionBase
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.PropertySet.writeAdditionalPropertiesToXml(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.GetAttachmentRequest.writeElementsToXml(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.writeBodyToXml(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.writeToXml(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.buildEwsHttpWebRequest(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.validateAndEmitRequest(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.internalGetAttachments(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.getAttachment(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Attachment.internalLoad(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ItemAttachment.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.medpro.roundrobinmailer.RoundRobinMailer.sendunreadmailtoRRRecpt(RoundRobinMailer.java:173)
    at com.medpro.roundrobinmailer.RoundRobinMailer.delegateAccessSearchEmailWithFilter(RoundRobinMailer.java:114)
    at com.medpro.roundrobinmailer.RoundRobinMailer.main(RoundRobinMailer.java:57)

The code breaks at :
      ia.load(ps);

This is driving me nuts.
Please help.

Thanks 
Tushar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in EWS Java. Fortunately, it has been open sourced and is available on Github:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api

See Issue #12. The problem is in ExchangeService.internalGetAttachments(). There is some very ugly code in there that uses an inexplicable mixture of generics and untyped collections. As a result, it winds up adding the whole PropertySet to a list when it should have copied over the individual PropertyDefinitionBase objects, which is why you're seeing the ClassCastException. Take a look. If it hasn't been fixed already, then it shouldn't be difficult to do on your own.

Answer (score 0):

/*
  @author rmansink

This method Downloads all the attachments associated with the Email

I think you are getting error because before load u need to bind the item.. following is the code which works fine... Tested and currently being used in my project.. hope it helps.. best of luck

*/

```
public static void getAttachments(ExchangeService service, ItemId id) throws Exception{

    Item item = Item.bind(service, id);
    item.load();
    if (item.getHasAttachments()){ 

        AttachmentCollection attachmentsCol = item.getAttachments();

        int NumberOfAttachments = attachmentsCol.getCount();

        System.out.println("Attchments being Downloaded:: "+NumberOfAttachments);
        String directoryName = "C:\\MSExchangeEmail\\WebContent\\attachments";
        File theDir = new File(directoryName);

        // if the directory does not exist, create it
        if (!theDir.exists()) {
          System.out.println("creating directory: " + directoryName);
          boolean result = false;

          try{

              result = theDir.mkdir();

           } catch(SecurityException se){
              //handle it
           }        
           if(result) {    
             System.out.println("DIR created: "+result);  
           }
        }  
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfAttachments; i++) { 

            FileAttachment attachment = (FileAttachment)attachmentsCol.getPropertyAtIndex(i); 
            attachment.load(directoryName+"\\"+attachment.getName());
        }
    } 

}
```

Comment: Hi Raj, got following error :
Attchments being Downloaded:: 3
java.lang.ClassCastException: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ItemAttachment cannot be cast to microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.FileAttachment
 at com.medpro.roundrobinmailer.RoundRobinMailer.sendunreadmailtoRRRecpt(RoundRobinMailer.java:170)
 at com.medpro.roundrobinmailer.RoundRobinMailer.delegateAccessSearchEmailWithFilter(RoundRobinMailer.java:107)
 at com.medpro.roundrobinmailer.RoundRobinMailer.main(RoundRobinMailer.java:50)

Comment: this has been happening to me since yesterday. and I while downloading the attachments using itemAttachment object, The api just freaks out and doesn't let me download anything

Comment: and when I try using ItemAttachment, the load function requires me to provide the parameters as PropertyDefinitionBase and I don't know how to cast the PropertSet object to PropertyDefinitionBase object.

Comment: instead of Item item = Item.bind(service, id) and then item.load() you can directly try this... I was also facing same problem with load and I tried this and it was sorted out... item = Item.bind(service, id, propertySet) --> for example [Item item = Item.bind(mailList.get(i).getService(), mailList.get(i).getItemId(),new PropertySet(ItemSchema.MimeContent))]

Comment: as the error is concerned have never used RoundRobinMailer, did my app with JavaMailer... code worked fine... Try the load one may be it will work fine...

PS: if possible let us see ur code may be others will also be able to help